# Possible deadlock in Util.showOptionDialog

Tags: install4j

Seen on install4j 6.0.4

The first screen of our installer displays an option dialog to ask the user if they wish to continue under certain circumstances, if they choose not to we call `installerContext.finish(-1)`.

In console mode if a user inputs `Ctrl+C`, nothing happens. If after that they input 'n' the installer attempts to exit but freezes.

I got a `jstack` of the process and I think there's some sort of deadlock between the `System.exit` call triggered by the installer context and the install4j shutdown hook which is waiting for the input to complete (`CommandSink.waitForFinish`).

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" #13 prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fab7841c800 nid=0x110e waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fab5f521000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000c2262a98> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:109)
    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:971)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.InstallerUtil.exit(InstallerUtil.java:161)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$6.run(ContextImpl.java:1191)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.exit(ContextImpl.java:1195)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.exit(InstallerContextImpl.java:310)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.finish(ContextImpl.java:865)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.finish(InstallerContextImpl.java:369)
    at com.acme.CustomCode.validate(MyCustomCode.java:64)
    at com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_8.eval(I4jScript_Internal_8.java:22)
    at com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_8.evaluate(I4jScript_Internal_8.java:26)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.Script.evaluate(Script.java:29)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(ContextImpl.java:181)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(ContextImpl.java:176)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runBooleanScript(ContextImpl.java:49)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runBooleanScript(ContextImpl.java:210)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.runValidationScript(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:124)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.handleScreen(ConsoleScreenExecutor.java:56)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.execute(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:81)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller$1.run(Controller.java:133)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)


"SIGINT handler" #30 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fab4c001000 nid=0x1128 in Object.wait() [0x00007fab5f422000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c3171798> (a com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor$1)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1245)
    - locked <0x00000000c3171798> (a com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor$1)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1319)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:106)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:123)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:167)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
    - locked <0x00000000c2262a98> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
    at java.lang.Terminator$1.handle(Terminator.java:52)
    at sun.misc.Signal$1.run(Signal.java:212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"shutdown hook" #12 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fab2c01c000 nid=0x112c in Object.wait() [0x00007fab5d19c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000ebb08610> (a com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.CommandSink)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.CommandSink.waitForFinish(CommandSink.java:54)
    - locked <0x00000000ebb08610> (a com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.CommandSink)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor$1.run(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:60)
```

Comment: I may have a fix for this problem, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a new build.

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to get back to this question but I was looking for cycle in which I could test the upgrade.

After testing it I see that the deadlock has been resolved. However what I see now is that sending the `Ctrl+C` signal doesn't have any immediate effect on the installer. However several screens later it bails out. Thoughts?

Comment: Actually it is completely ignored. My installer was ending due to unrelated reasons. Shouldn't `Ctrl+C` throw `UserCanceledException`?

Comment: Ctrl-C works for me in console mode on Linux. On what platform are you trying this?

Comment: Sorry. I know this is months later. I'm testing this in an Ubuntu 4.14 VM.

Ctrl + C doesn't have any effect at any point.

Also, I'm now testing with Install4j 6.1.5